# Expression for the sum of submodules of a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $[u_1,u_2]$ denote the free $\Bbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$ with generators $u_1$ and $u_2$, i.e., $$[u_1,u_2]:=u_1\Bbb{Z}\oplus u_2\Bbb{Z}.$$ Let $M=[1,\theta]$. Except for $\theta$, which is irrational, every variable in sight here is an integer.

It is clear that any rank-$2$ submodule of $M$ can be written in the form $[a,b+c\theta]$, where we can assume w.l.o.g. that $a$ and $c$ are positive and that $0\le b\le a-1$. Subject to these restrictions, the representation is unique, and can be taken as a canonical representation.

For submodules with canonical representations:

$M_1=[a,b+c\theta]\subseteq M \\ M_2=[d,e+f\theta]\subseteq M,$

I want to write down the canonical representation of the submodule $$M_1+M_2=\{m_1+m_2\mid m_1\in M_1, m_2\in M_2\},$$ but I'm stuck on a detail. I have this:

$M_1+M_2=[g_1,h+g_2\theta]$

where $g_1=\gcd(a,d,bf-ce)$ and $g_2=\gcd(c,f)$. For $h$, I have the system of linear congruences:

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{c}{g_2}h\equiv b\pmod{g_1} \\ \dfrac{f}{g_2}h\equiv e\pmod{g_1}\end{cases}$.

I need to know that such an $h$ exists, and that we can determine it uniquely up to congruence modulo $g_1$, and that's where I'm stuck. For example, the first congruence has a solution iff $\gcd\left(\frac{c}{g_2}, g_1\right)| b$. It's clear to me that, if $t|\frac{c}{g_2}$ and $t|g_1$, then we have $t|bf$, but we need $t|b$. From looking at examples, the system always seems to have a unique solution, even though both congruences might individually have multiple ones.

I don't know whether I'm missing something obvious, or whether my approach is all wrong, or what. Any help, hints or insight anyone can offer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I have the wrong expression there for $g_1$. The other one, $g_2=\gcd(c,f)$ is perfect, and we should define $c'=\dfrac{c}{g_2}, f'=\dfrac{f}{g_2}$, two relatively prime integers. Then the formula we really need is:

$g_1=\gcd(a,d,bf'- c'e)$

Then the congruences we need are:

$\begin{cases}c'h\equiv b\pmod{g_1} \\ f'h\equiv e\pmod{g_1}\end{cases}$

Now, any divisor of $c'$ and $g_1$ is relatively prime to $f'$. By the definition of $g_1$, it must divide $bf'$, but because of relative primeness to $f'$, it must also divide $b$. Similarly with the second congruence. Uniqueness is also not hard to show, once we have the correct definition for $g_1$.

I figured this out by just trying different examples to poke at different parts of it. The one that finally made it clear was adding $M_1=[9,4+18\theta]$ and $M_2=[3,1+6\theta]$. Their sum contains $1=(4+18\theta) -3(1+6\theta)$, but my previous definition of $g_1$ was not capturing that.